# Minify CSS removes properties with var() in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, minify

I'm using the https://github.com/DevFactoryCH/minify package for minify the css and js files.
but I'm getting issue with it when I compile my css files then minify remove the var() properties.
this is my code with css variables

```
:root {
  --primary-color: #1d85b9;
  }
.info.icon-info {
  background: #fff;
  color: var(--primary-color)!important;
}
```

this is home.blade.php file code

```
{!! inline_css(Minify::stylesheet(array(
  '/css/bootstrap.css',
  '/css/style.css',
  '/css/label.css',
))) !!}
```

its compile without var() properties
Output:

```
.info.icon-info {
      background: #fff;
}
```

Please suggest the alternate minify package for that

Comment: Waht code does it produce - i.e. what is the value of color when you inspect .info.icon-info in your browser's dev tools?

Comment: There is an open issue that has not been addressed by the authors of that package since 2019: https://github.com/DevFactoryCH/minify/issues/53

Comment: Perhaps check into a library that has some recent effort? This hasn't effectively been touched since 2015: https://github.com/DevFactoryCH/minify/graphs/code-frequency

Comment: @AHaworth I Update the output on question

Answer (score 1):

Stop using old, slow, and outdated technologies. This includes both the CSS minification library you're using, and PHP itself.

This one for NPM was updated 3 months ago: https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-minify

This one for PHP was updated 10 months ago: https://github.com/matthiasmullie/minify

Or, perhaps try this API out:
https://www.toptal.com/developers/cssminifier/api